# Re-Writing VBA office Addins

Tags: ms-office, add-in, office-interop, office365

In my company, We need to rewrite a suite of addins for our company (that are currently in VBA). With BYOD coming on the horizon, and Office 365, how can we make sure our addins are future proof and in line with MSs road map?"

Comment: nothing is future proof.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, nothing is future proof, but the way to go today is by using the 'new' OfficeJS Addins. In the end they will be x-plat (Multi Platform), even available in Office Online (i.e. Office365) as well.

Goto http://dev.office.com for the specifications.

You need to keep in mind that these interfaces are still under development and not completely in par with the .COM object model (you used to know from VBA and/or VSTO) but they are working hard to get this done -and- making it available on the various other platforms such as MAC, iPad, etc.